# Does Azure Blob Storage support Server Side encryption

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

Looking at Amazon S3 Server side encryption where the encryption and decryption are managed by server itself. Do we have such option in Azure? I know that we have client side encryption available in Azure SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, no. Azure Blob Storage does not support Server-Side encryption.

**UPDATE: 05-APRIL-2016**

Server-Side Encryption is now available in Azure Storage. Please see this link for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-service-encryption/.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we don't support encryption @rest for any of the Azure storage services, but this is something we are looking at.

Comment: Thanks @Dinesh. Any roadmap?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SSE support is now available as a tech preview in certain regions.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-service-encryption/